# Python imaplib uid fetch command error

Tags: python, imaplib

I tried to fetch a message content in the following way

```
result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, "( FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT FROM DATE)] BODYSTRUCTURE)")
```

It worked well when I was connecting to a private mail server "mail.example.com"
But it returns exception when I used "imap.gmail.com"

```
error: UID command error: BAD ['Could not parse command']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think gmail doesnot support detailed search like HEADER.FIELDS....
So I tried the following option for gmail server and it worked really well

```
result, data = m.uid('fetch', num, "(FLAGS BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODYSTRUCTURE)")
```